# Reverse an Array but i'm getting a segmentation error

Tags: c++

What am I doing wrong ???
It is giving me an error of segmentation fault .
I don't know what memory  i'm accessing ??

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    int n;
    int arr[n];
    
    cin>>t;
    cin>>n;

    // taking array elements from user
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    
     // reverse of the array
     for(int i=n-1; i>=0;i--)
    {
        cout<<arr[i];
    }
    //code
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int arr[n];` but the value of `n` is undefined at that moment. I don't think C++ has VLAs anyway (the code is not C, where support for the VLA is optional).

Comment: Even if you reordered things to be `int n; cin >> n; int arr[n];`, you'd _still_ be using a nonstandard extension to have a [variable length array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). If you want a homogenous sequence container whose size is only determined at runtime, I suggest taking a look at the [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Watch out for compiler warnings - do not ignore a single one of them.

Comment: FYI, remove the C language tag.  The `C` language does not have `std::cin`, and doesn't allow operator or function overloading.  Thus `cin >> arr[i]` is a right shift in the C language.

Comment: Since you don't know the quantity of data at compile time use `std::vector` and the `push_back` method.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> int n;
> ```

You've default initialised this variable. Thus, the value is indeterminate.

> ```
> int arr[n];
> ```

Here, you use that indeterminate value. Thus, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

There are "data flow" languages where using a variable will stop execution  waiting for you to initialise it later and continue. C++ isn't such language. You **must** initialise everything before using the value.

---

Besides that, `n` isn't a compile time constant expression. Because the size of the array variable isn't compile time conastant, the progarm is ill-formed in C++.

If you want an array to have a dynamic size, you can use dynamic storage. Simplest way to create a dynamic array is to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you are trying to declare a variable length array

```
int n;
int arr[n];
```

Variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature. Moreover you are using an uninitialized variable n as the size of the array.

Either declare the array with an expected maximum size or use standard container `std::vector<int>`. At least you should write provided that the compiler supports variable length arrays

```
int t;
int n = 1;

cin>>t;
cin>>n;

if ( n < 1 ) n = 1;
int arr[n];

//...
```

Also you are not reversing an array. You are trying to output an array in the reverse order.

To reverse an array you could use standard algorithm `std::reverse` or you can write an appropriate loop yourself as for example

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
{
    // or use std::swap( arr[i], arr[n-i-1] );
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[n-i-1];
    arr[n-i-1] = tmp;
}
```

and then you can output the reversed array.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to define array with Unknown size in C++ so `int arr[n];` is **Wrong!** and if you have to use arrays and not know the size of it , you should use dynamic array with Pointers like this : int* a = new int[n] and also Deallocate Heap memory with `Delete []array_name` at end of your program and if it is possible for you not use arrays It's better for you use vectors because the size of it is dynamic.

**look at this with vectors :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
//by : Salar Ashgi
int main()
{
    int k;
    cout<<"Enter number of elements ?\n";
    cin>>k;
    vector<int> v;
    cout<<"--------------------\n";
    int x;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter num "<<i+1<<" : ";
        cin>>x;
        v.push_back(x);
    }
    
    reverse(v.begin(),v.end());//algorithm.h
    cout<<"Reverse : \n";
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```